# Plotly : How to annotate multiple lines in Plotly Express?

Tags: python, dataframe, express, plotly, visualization

I want to create a line chart with multiple lines sharing the same x and y axis.
Fortunately, newest version of Plotly seems to allow multiple inputs as y.
Example:
`px.line(df,x,[y1,y2])` works fine.

Unfortunately, I want to add text as datapoint annotations and this does not work in the same way.

My goal is to create a lineplot with multiple lines and each datapoint annotated with its y_value in the same color as the corresponding line.

Ty for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps not the most elegant approach, but the complete snippet below will produce the following figure. Some central parts of the snippets are:

#### Approach:

```
for i, d in enumerate(fig.data):
    for j, a in enumerate(d.x):
        fig.add_annotation(x=a, y = d.y[j], text = str(d.y[j])[:5],
                          showarrow = False,
                          yshift = 10,
                          font=dict(color=d.line.color, size=12))
```

#### Plot 1:

[image]

If you'd like to follow other [color cycles](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/) for your annotations, just include:

```
colors = px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet
```

And replace:

```
font=dict(color=d.line.color, size=12)
```

with:

```
font=dict(color=colors[i], size=12)
```

And get:

#### Plot 2:

[image]

I'd be happy to go into all the details if this is something you could use.

#### Complete code:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# data
df = px.data.stocks().tail(10)
df = df.drop(['AMZN', 'AAPL'], axis = 1)

df.set_index('date', inplace = True)
colors = px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet

fig = px.line(df, x = df.index, y = df.columns)

for i, d in enumerate(fig.data):
    for j, a in enumerate(d.x):
        fig.add_annotation(x=a, y = d.y[j], text = str(d.y[j])[:5],
                           showarrow = False,
                           yshift = 10,
                           font=dict(color=d.line.color, size=12)
#                            font=dict(color=colors[i], size=12)
                          )


fig.show()
```